# Rails Routing with Namespace and format (for api)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, namespaces, routes

I know this isn't RESTful, but for now, I'm trying to set up an api/v1 controller.  Ideally I would like to call it like this:

```
site.com/api/v1/verify.xml
```

But right now I can't get the .xml to work.  I have the following route so far:

```
map.namespace :api do |api|
  api.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
end
```

I can do `/api/v1/verify` but I don't think it is using the route above.  For some reason it is still hitting my catch all route also even though it displays the right page.

```
map.connect '*path', :controller => 'application', :action => 'redirect_main'
```

So:
1) how do I get the `.format` on there?
2) And how do I make it not hit my catch all route?

Comment: don't you have to have a namespace for "v1", or is "v1" your controller?

Comment: v1 is the controller. Again, not the cleanest way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1) how do I get the .format on there?

```
api.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
```

> 2) And how do I make it not hit my
>   catch all route?

I believe your catch-all route should be the last one on `routes.rb`. This way it should work...

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't using named routes or resources, you have to specify every combination of path you want to handle, including the file extension.

Adding `api.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'` back to your `api` namespace will give you access to `params[:format]` to respond to.

Comment: `map.connect` or `api.connect`?

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't you just need to add `.:format`?

```
map.namespace :api do |api|
  api.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
end
```